# Can't load javascript to HTML page in Node.js with NetBeans

Tags: javascript, node.js, netbeans

I am working with NetBeans IDE and Node.js.

My homepage is `index.html` and I added link to a javascript file `client.js` inside my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./Sources/client.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

It doesn't find my script and I don't understand why.
You can see on the Network monitor that it tried to find it with the correct path but it failed:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your **path isn't correct**, There is no actual Sources directory at default Node/HTML5 Netbeans generated project.

You can open the project directory and confirm this, after that fix to correct path which may be `public` or similar.

Comment: You are right, there is not such folder `Sources`.  I tried to change the path to:  `src="./client.js"`, `src="client.js"` and `src="./public/client.js"` but I keep getting errors.

Comment: The problem was because the `client.js` wasn't under the public folder. After putting it under the public folder there was an access to this file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use express or an alternative.
using express this is how you will do it:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = new express();

app.use(express.static('path to folder with files'));

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendfile('index.html');
});

app.listen(8080);
```

and then it will load it correctly.
for more read the express docs...
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html

Comment: Express is already installed. But I can't run your javascript code because I can't load the javascript code from the HTML which is the my original problem.

Comment: You said you're using node js, i assume that means you are running a server, so what you need to do is start your server like that and load the html file to it like i wrote.
nevigate to the project folder in the shell and run the js file with "node file.js"

Comment: I understand. I noticed that my project was with Express disabled.